# Printing name of field with highest value?

Tags: arcpy, error-000539

I am trying to find the field with highest area value in each row of the 5 fields. Now I have found the highest value. But it doesn't really do me any good if I couldn't find which field is that max.

[image]

I have some rudimentary understanding and practice of Python. The very similar answer here:

[need to find max value among fields AND PRINT FIELD NAME](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169770/need-to-find-max-value-among-fields-and-print-field-name)

When I applied the code, it always gave me a failure, which is probably due to my lack of understanding of Python.

> Error 000539, Python syntax.

The code I adapted from that question is shown as below:

```
import arcpy

table = "L:\......\ParcelSummary.dbf"
fields = [ !SUM_acres_! , !SUM_acres1! , !SUM_acre_1! , !SUM_acre_2! , !SUM_acre_3! ]
n = len(fields)


maxfield = "Highest"
maxname = "HighestF"
arcpy.AddField_management(table, maxfield, "FLOAT")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, maxname, "TEXT")

fields2 = fields[:] # shallow copy
fields2.extend([maxfield, maxname])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, fields2) as cursor:
for row in cursor:

    check = row[:n]
    maxval = max(check)

    row[-2:] = maxval, fields[check.index(maxval)]

    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Also, a pretty basic question about this: shall I put the code into the Field Calculator expression or shall I put it in Pre-Logic Script Code? If I put them in the Codeblock, then what shall my expression be?

As for the field names, the ones shown in the picture are the aliases of the fields instead of names.

---

My exact process and the error message I got.

[image: Field Calculator]
[image: Error Message]

Seems like the error is from line 1

[image]

The picture above shows the first few lines of the expression, what could have gone wrong here?

Comment: What is the actual error or behavior? It looks like this should work, minus the fact that you are loading in the XML metadata file instead of the actual DBF table...

Comment: Error 000539, Python syntax. The xml path was like that when I copied the path, just corrected it. No idea what actually went wrong. I should put the code in the expression right? Thanks

Comment: What line is the syntax error referring to? At a guess, it's probably the `for row in cursor:` bit. That and everything below it should be indented one more level (it's inside the `with`) unless that didn't paste properly.

Comment: How are you executing this?  If you're not in Field Calculator you don't want the exclamation points around the field names they will need to be strings.

Comment: I do use it in the Field Calculator. Let me update my results and process real quick. Thanks

Comment: Turns out the error is in the 1st line. Any thoughts on the expression? Thanks

Comment: Where is the CalculateField line in your code sample?

Comment: This may be where I missed, I need a CalculateField line? Where shall I put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
def compMaxField(table, fields, maxFldName, maxValName):
  arcpy.AddField_management(table, maxFldName, 'TEXT') # field name with max value
  arcpy.AddField_management(table, maxValName, 'FLOAT') # the max value
  with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, fields + [maxFldName, maxValName]) as cur:
    for row in cur: # everything inside a context must be indented
      maxVal = max(row[:-2]) # get the max value, skip the output fields
      maxFld = fields[row.index(maxVal)] # find out the corresponding field name
      # make a new row
      row = list(row[:-2]) + [maxFld, maxVal]
      cur.updateRow(row)
```

Place this into the pre-logic section, then just call it from the calculator like this:

```
compMaxField("L:\\......\\ParcelSummary.dbf",
             ['SUM_acres_' , 'SUM_acres1', 'SUM_acre_1', 'SUM_acre_2', 'SUM_acre_3'],
             'MaxArea', 'MaxField')
```

As @Florjan said, the backslashes in the path should be double-escaped, or you can use a raw string with the `r` prefix.

Comment: Small adjustment, should be `for row in cur:` not cursor

Comment: @AndrewLebron Check the 'Show Codeblock' checkbox in the Field Calculator window.  This will open the Pre-Logic Script Code window.  Then try using the above code provided by Jan.

Comment: Updated, it should work now, accounting for both errors. Thanks @Brian!

Comment: Thank you so much! Weird that it worked today not yesterday considering I did the same thing. Anyway, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

Before the dbf-file insert "r" letter:

`table = r"c:\.....\name.dbf"`

Change the expressed field names and if you take any error share it:

`fields = [ "SUM_acres_" , "SUM_acres1" , "SUM_acre_1" , "SUM_acre_2" , "SUM_acre_3" ]`

Comment: Thank you. Changed the path and quotation marks but still get error message in line 1. Just edited the original post with the expression I have in Field Calculator.

Comment: You script with my suggestions should be run from python terminal not to field calculation. 
If you wanna try the field calculation method get the @jan reply, he has adapted it for field calculation.

Comment: using field calculation forget my reply, check "code block" and copy and paste Jan code. Separately first block paste it to "Pre-Logic" space and second block  paste it to last space.

Comment: i cannot help for Jan part cause never used searchcursor on field calculation, i have to test it for myself ^_^