# Python-code "max value among fields and print field name" working in ArcGIS Pro command line, not in script-tool

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, cursor

I tried [this code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169770/need-to-find-max-value-among-fields-and-print-field-name/458255#458255) in ArcGIS Pro.

I am getting the code to work great in command line. However, trying to script a tool out it in ArcGIS Pro.

Getting an error:

> File "", line 13, in AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute
> 'extend'.

Here is the code:

```
import arcpy
#input data and fields to find maximum
table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
fields = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
n = len(fields)

# Add fields to input table to store maximum and field name
maxfield = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
maxname = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
arcpy.AddField_management(table, maxfield, "DOUBLE")
arcpy.AddField_management(table, maxname, "TEXT"

fields2 = fields[:] # shallow copy
fields2.extend([maxfield, maxname])

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(table, fields2) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:

        # Look at the first n values
        check = row[:n]
        maxval = max(check)

        # Get the index position of the maxval and use it slice into field list
        # which gives us the field name
        # only update the last two rows
        row[-2:] = maxval, fields[check.index(maxval)]

        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GetParamterAsText, so the input fields variable is a string.
If you print the fields variable using arcpy.AddMessage you will see how the GetParameterAsText handles the multiple field inputs as text. Convert the input string to a list.

```
fields = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1).replace("'", "").split(";")
```